# How can I find a camera with remote viewfinder and shutter (via phone or tablet)?

Tags: camera-recommendation, remote, tethering

Looking for an camera with the following features:

- compact (smaller is better)
- with image stabilization
- **has remote viewfinder** via wifi (enough 10-12m) - so, have some application for phones or tablets.
- is possible to **control remotely** (via the phone app) the basic camera functions, especially:

  - the **shutter** (must have)
  - **zoom** (must have)
  - photo/video mode switching (this an "would be nice")

Unfortunately, any feature-search sites (know two: dpreview.com and neocamera.com) doesn't have search criteria for the "remote viewfinder" or so.

Via googling i find Samsung cameras (WB850f, 150F, ST200F) - (for remote viewfinder) but know nothing about the application, what allowing control in the camera.

And the main question is, exists any other cameras with the above features?

EDIT:

Here are some comments about zooming. While I'm probably don't understand the "mechanics" inside the camera (motorized or whatever) but here already exists **many** cameras what allow remote zoom via *infrared control*.

For example: many Canon cameras (G1, G2, G5, G6, Pro90, S1-IS and several others), Olympus (e.g. C-2020, C-2040, C-2100, C-4040, C-40, C-730, MJU300, MJU400 and many others), Pentax (A10, A20, A30, A40-my current, S-40), and many Samsung and Sony cameras too.

Therefore, with simple analogy i was hoping than if it is possible zoom a camera with IR-remote, there *can be* an zoom via wifi too..

Unfortunately, it is not a feature about care many people (and review sites neither) therefore asking here. :)

Comment: A requirement is to have remote control of zoom? I've never seen this before, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: I want replace my old pentax what is currently controlled with RC "gentled" and analog video link. Now i can control zoom and shutter - but looking for pure digital-wifi replacement. But, know you some "remote viewfinder" cameras without zoom?

Comment: I assume you've found the Sony QX10 by now. Also, I've got the Samsung DV300F and it can zoom via the remote viewfinder app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any DSLR or P&S with motorized zoom, AFAIK only video cameras have such ability and many of them can be controlled remotely too.

I'm not sure about your budget, but wireless tethering is possible with many brand new DSLR cameras. it seems you just didn't know the correct terms and what to look for.

For example [Nikon D5200](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/910146-REG/nikon_1501_d5200_digital_slr_camera.html). using [Nikon WU-1a Wireless Mobile Adapter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/856201-REG/Nikon_27081_WU_1a_Wireless_Mobile_Adapter.html), you can connect it to your Android and iOS device and control your camera and more.

[image: WU-1a Wireless Mobile Adapter]
[image: Wireless Mobile Adapter Utility]
From [Nikon website](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d5200/features05.htm#a13)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to nikon site, will take a look. (and I edited my question about the "zooming" in the cameras, too) - ad budget: of course, money plays his role - but the main needs are: small size, and remote view, zoom and shutter. :) Thank you for answer.

Comment: Great. In the Nikon site i just found an new search term "remote shooting". I'm looking for "remote viewfinder" and this a term what seems using Samsung only. English is not my primary language, so i'm happy and going to search... ;) ;)

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I'm probably found my "dream" camera (Panasonic ZS-30) - just because you pointed me to "remote shooting" search term. I just found this discussion: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/51240396 ;) (has much better battery as Samsung)