Are there cameras that I can zoom remotely?
I'm looking for a camera that I can zoom with a remote control, whether that's with software on a PC, or a wired controller.  I'd like to avoid controlling it wirelessly.  I'd like to combine that camera with something like a Bescor MP-1AC pan/tilt head.  Of course, I'd also like to be able to adjust ISO, aperture, and shutter speed remotely, and control the shutter remotely.  My Canon T3i has software for remote control, but since there's no motor connected to the lens for zoom, it can't zoom remotely.
I'm aware that there are cameras like a Canon CR-N100, but I'd like to spend less money than that.  I'm thinking more like a point and shoot, bridge, or mirrorless camera.  The intended use case is for still photography in confined spaces.

Have you looked at Remote Shooting via the Canon Camera Connect app ?  https://www.canon.co.uk/get-inspired/tips-and-techniques/remote-shooting/ find a compatible Canon camera, and you can remote control the zoom along with the other stuff (and of course 'pt' separately with your head). Lots of options, obviously the better ones cost more. Saw lots when I was last at the Society of Cinematographers expo a while back. Mount a drone with a ptz head without flying it too..

Yeah, that would be a good solution.  Can it control the zoom on every recent Canon camera with electronic zooming?

https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4297575 - this old thread was useful, when using a powershot / separately, this app seems a potential alternative -Camera Connect & Control

also https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/51240396 (from an older thread on here) https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/38562/104052

The Panasonic Lumix TZ series of compact "Super Zoom" cameras includes at least some that provide full control, including optical zoom, shooting, focus, exposure, etc. via an Android or iPhone smartphone/tablet app. The app supports a number of models
but unfortunately the Panasonic web site does not make it clear which models support remote zoom control.
